# How do I determine if a computer is running XP Service pack 3

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-installer

Using either the registry or the file system.  The reason for the restriction is that I am doing this as an MSI conditional statement.

Cheers!

Comment: Seeing as how you can right click and go to the properties on My Computer, this should be very simple for someone to answer with experience about where this information is stored. Sadly that's not me :)

Comment: The title of this question got my hopes up, and then I read the part about registry or file system. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

under registry key

*HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion*

look for key pair:

*CurrentVersion = Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3*

Comment: CSDVersion key has a "Service Pack n" value.  Which is good enough for what I need.

Answer (score 4):

You should find enough information to determine the OS service pack (in the worst case you can always use the build string) in the following registry key:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

Comment: Cheers! Where exactly under this key would you find the service pack info?

Comment: In Service Pack 3 you should expect to find a key named CSDVersion with value "Service Pack 3"

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an MSI, you should be able to use the **VersionNT** and **ServicePackLevel** properties right in the conditional statement.

eg. The following code checks for Windows XP sp3 or greater:

```
VersionNT=501 And ServicePackLevel>2
```

You can also check the **WindowsBuild** property if you also need the build number.

Answer (score 1):

The [VerifyVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725492(VS.85).aspx) function should allow you to check the version of Windows being run meets your application's requirements, without the pitfalls that can occur with checking for an exact version with [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451.aspx) (such as breaking on major version changes - your application will most likely run on Vista, and Windows 7, and future versions not yet developed).

Answer (score -1):

"Run" (Windows key + r or start/run) msinfo32 or sysdm.cpl

Comment: this is for xp, don't know about 7/vista etc.